# Getting Linux kernel debug information after a kernel crash

Tags: c, linux, debugging, linux-kernel

Is there a way to get kernel previous debug information after kernel crash  occurs.

I am trying to develop a kernel module which basically captures IP packets in the IP layer inside the kernel network stack and after some modification I have to send the same packet back to the NIC for transmission.

During all these processes I'm writing debug information with the help of **printk()**. But if any thing goes wrong and a kernel failure occurs, we have to restart the system. Is there a way to get my previous debug information, because after rebooting the debug information is not present as I try to get it by **dmesg** command?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Actually, the */var/log/dmesg* file contains the current boot print message log. The */var/log/kern.log* file contains your previous boot kernel print message log in [Ubuntu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_%28operating_system%29). In other Linux flavours it will contain in the */var/log/messages* file in Fedora, etc..

Answer (score 5):

Kernel log messages can be viewed in `/var/log/dmesg` files even after restart of the system.

There will be so many files with dmesg.X, and those files are previous kernel logs. `dmesg` is the latest file.

See *[difference between dmesg and /var/log/kern.log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11412950/difference-between-dmesg-and-var-log-kern-log)*

Answer (score 2):

You could try to interact with your hung system by entering [magic SysRq](http://kernel.org/doc/Documentation/sysrq.txt) key sequences via your keyboard or a serial console.

Comment: actually when i run my module system just hangs so i m not able do anything & i have to force reboot.i m trying with  magic SysRq key sequences but i m not getting the result..

Comment: You may have to enable *magic sysrq* during your kernel's configuration and build.

Answer (score 2):

Recent versions of Linux support [crash dumps](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/kernel-crash-dump.html). When successful, these will include a full dump of memory, including kernel log messages and stack traces.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, the crash information (dmesg) is present in the location /var/crash/.
Here we have the folders for every system crash. Folder names like 127.0.0.1-date-time. vmcore-dmesg.txt are present inside the folders. From these file, we have get the dmesg which are executed before the crash.

Comment: works for RHEL 9.3

Answer (score 0):

GNOME Logs is a very useful software for that. You can limit the log messages to the last session and easily read what the last messages before the crash were.